# Missing layout_height attribute stack trace?

Tags: android

I'm continuing to dig through marketplace crash reports, and have come across another one which I can't make any sense of. The stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #17: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5319)
at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5271)
at android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams.<init>(AbsListView.java:6398)
at android.widget.AbsListView.generateLayoutParams(AbsListView.java:6035)
at android.widget.AbsListView.generateLayoutParams(AbsListView.java:96)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:477)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter$MenuAdapter.getView(ListMenuPresenter.java:253)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2212)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12863)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2256)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12863)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2552)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So I'm being told that layout_height is missing in one of my layout files on a line #17? But I don't know which layout file from the stack trace. I'm going through them one by one to see if I forgot the layout_height attribute anywhere, but I have lots of them and wanted to see if I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: Can u post your xml file here?

Comment: Normally the error will give you more details - can you post the full error report here?

Comment: Hi all, that's the thing - that's the full stack trace that Market gives me. And there is no mention of *which* xml file this is happening in. So I'm completely in the dark. My app is quite large and I'm going through the xml files one by one to see if I forgot layout_height - insane.

Comment: the only thing I can suggest is that this line may have some answers 'at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter$MenuAdapter.getView(ListMenuPresenter.java:253)' - look at source code here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/com/android/internal/view/menu/ListMenuPresenter.java#ListMenuPresenter.MenuAdapter.getView%28int%2Candroid.view.View%2Candroid.view.ViewGroup%29