# How do I find this RuntimeException in Android (stack trace)?

Tags: java, android, stack-trace, runtimeexception

I have this strack trace from the Developer Console on Google Play so I have no way to reproduce this exception cause I don't know what triggers it. The user also didn't leave any message, so...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #17: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5319)
at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5271)
at android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams.<init>(AbsListView.java:6398)
at android.widget.AbsListView.generateLayoutParams(AbsListView.java:6035)
at android.widget.AbsListView.generateLayoutParams(AbsListView.java:96)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:477)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter$MenuAdapter.getView(ListMenuPresenter.java:253)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2212)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12863)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2256)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12863)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2552)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How do I pinpoint the problem?

Comment: Just found a similar question without an answer, not very comforting :/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483253/missing-layout-height-attribute-stack-trace

Comment: Any chance one of your XML layouts items has a missing layout_height attribute? Did you try using lint to locate a possible XML bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Android's internal error, nothing in your code. You don't even see your app's code in stack trace, and your app works on many other devices.

I'm getting similar occasional crash reports, and also similar crashes on some Android versions (using [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra)). I've seen "You must supply a layout_height attribute" unexpected crash a few times.

If you use ACRA or similar, sometimes you just get reports for which your app is not responsible at all.

Comment: No, I don't use ACRA. So, should I just ignore error reports which don't include any of my app's methods in the stack trace?

Comment: Generally don't ignore bugs, but in cases that crash doesn't happen in your code, even doesn't pass your code, it works on most devices, and you see no way to fix on your side, you just must ignore. You may search if such bug exist in Android or report one: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/advsearch

Answer (score 0):

Message says - "You must supply a layout_height attribute."
So, double check that all your components have layout_height attribute.

I also had mention "menu" in this stack. It is generated by system. Double check that your all menus have valid items (at least not zero items) all the time.